# How to upgrade JSLint in Aptana?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana, jslint

I am using the Aptana plugin for eclipse  - how to I upgrade the JSLint version being used to validate my JavaScript code?

It is complaining about my 'use strict" statement saying:
"expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where should something like this be asked?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Aptana steps for configuring jslint:

1. Go to window > prefrences > search validation
2. here you will get JSLint validator just activate and and rebuild your project.

Similar to eclipse  do a "ctrl + shift + f" whenever you are editing a js file.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work, but I'll share what I found anyway in case it points somebody in the right direction.

If you look in your Eclipse plugins directory (probably HOME/.eclipse), you'll find com.aptana.editor.js_${VERSION}.jar.  In this JAR is a version of JSLint (named fulljslint.js).  I tried updating this file in the JAR with the latest version, but I saw no difference in JSLint's behavior within Eclipse.  It seems to be getting the JSLint source from somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

In Aptana Studio 3 you can set individual JSLint options. This is how I did it.

Open the preferences and go to:

Aptana Studio -> Validation

Select JSLint Validator

You will then see a text box with the options defined in JSON.

The option you need to add is
 "sloppy" : true

Then of course click Apply or OK to save the changes.

Check out the JSLint web site for a list of all the options you can set.

(Sorry, I misread your question, this is how you would switch off the validation of the missing "strict" pragma. However, I had to add it because I was not using "strict" mode, so presumably it is now in the latest version of Studio 3?)